# How do I specify the icon to use in the Keychain authorisation dialog

Tags: cocoa, macos

I'm using `SecKeychainFindGenericPassword()` to get an application password that I have previously saved with `SecKeychainAddGenericPassword()`. As expected, MacOS gives the user a dialog asking them to approve the keychain access. However the icon superimposed over the lower right of the padlock is a generic document icon, not my application's icon.

I can't see anything in the Keychain Services References about specifying the icon, so I would assume that the OS just uses your application icon. My .icns file (referenced in the info.plist) has all possible sizes and bitmaps populated according to Iconographer so I'm really not sure where to look next.

Hoping there is an obvious gotcha that someone can point me to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s usually because your application is running from a directory that isn’t readable by other users. The authentication dialog obviously runs in another process and it needs to be able to get your icon from the bundle.

Comment: That wasn't it, but it was enough of a hint to get me there. The keychain dialog ignores what is in your Info.plist and reads a file called Icons.icns in your app's resources folder. In my case the file was called icons.icns (which matched the plist) and the app was on a case-sensitive volume! Solution was to both rename file and change plist to Icons.icns

Comment: Actually - scratch that. I can't make it work on a case sensitive volume at all. Oh well, it's a very minor display only issue for a very small percentage of users, and another rdar...

Answer (score 1):

This is an access right problem as Chris Suter mention earlier.
The name of the icon in the plist is irrelevant the file pointed in the app bundle Info.plist will be used (CFBundleIconFile) in the elevation process (if not specified a custom one to the elevator)
Try it on a Lion or newer OS and you will find that any app you copied in your home is protected against the world (that has no access at all) therefore the elevator can not read the icon.

Answer (score 0):

Prior to the deprecation of `kSecCustomIconItemAttr`, the [Keychain Services Reference (2003)](http://sysdoc.doors.ch/APPLE/keychainServRef.pdf) had this to say:

> `kSecCustomIconItemAttr`
>
> Identifies the custom icon attribute.
>   You use this tag to set or get a value
>   of type `Boolean` that indicates whether
>   the item has an application-specific
>   icon. To do this, **you must also set
>   the attribute value identified by the
>   tag `kSecTypeItemAttr` to a file type
>   for which there is a corresponding
>   icon in the desktop database, and set
>   the attribute value identified by the
>   tag `kSecCreatorItemAttr` to an
>   appropriate application creator type.**
>   If a custom icon corresponding to the
>   item’s type and creator can be found
>   in the desktop database, it will be
>   displayed by Keychain Access.
>   Otherwise, default icons are used.

Perhaps try setting the `kSecCreatorItemAttr` and `kSecTypeItemAttr` attributes.

Comment: I read this as being to set the custom icon for the security entity as displayed in keychain access (which it doesn't in OSX) rather than the app itself. Certainly creator types are very deprecated. Anyway, bereft of other ideas I'll give it a go (and if it works will then have to dig out the creator code registration page on some long forsaken Apple site!)